# cakephp truncate helper not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

e.g. (file = `views/elements/photos/tag.ctp`)

In this element I have to show a description about that photo. 
I want to truncate the description text, so i'm using the Truncate 
function of the Text Core Helper but this throws the following 
exception

```
echo $this->Text->truncate($photo['Photo']['description'], 30,array(  'ending' => '...', 'exact' => false,'html' => true ));

Fatal error: Call to a member function truncate() on a non-object i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next time, please post the full error message.

It looks like you didn't include the helper within the Controller you are using here.

Make sure, you have the following within your controller:

```
var $helpers = array('Text');
```

Comment: I added this line in my app_controller and all controllers.. but still same issue

Comment: I calling this element from my layout.ctp file $this->element('photos/tag');

Comment: I just tried it like you, no problem, works like it should. I just added the line in my AppController. It's not needed in the other controllers, if you put it in your AppController.

Comment: yes at first i put in app_controller and then try its not worked.. then i put in all my controller and then try ..its not worked... but finally for quick fix i use substr only on that page.. but remaining pages i used this code.. its working fine

Comment: I ran into a similar situation in a CakePHP 1.3 app I maintain.  `$this->Text->truncate()` works elsewhere in the app, but not in one particular place despite verifying the helper was loaded.  I ended up using substr in that particular place.